# ElasticApmInstrumentation matcher constructor super

Tags: instrumentation, byte-buddy, elastic-apm

Is it possible to write matcher for ElasticApmInstrumentation that will capture constructor of child class only?

I mean currently I use `ElementMatcher.isConstructor()` but some classes use in the constructor call `super()` and this triggers call of on the same object.

In case there are more levels I get even more duplications.
Is there a way how to avoid it?

Please note as a matcher for class I need to use parent class to capture whole group of classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve it by using `@Advice.Origin("#t")` origin and `@Advice.This` instance.

Then I compared `origin.equals(instance.getClass().getName())`.

I was not able to avoid the instrumentation directly but I was able to filter out duplications.

Answer (score 1):

The matching is done based on the shape, not the implementation. This is not possible for this reason.